# TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mais uma dúvida básica da minha parte. Sou 'Pythonista' nível super básico e estou tentando simplesmente ler um texto linha por linha e fazer um `split` cada vez que encontro um sinal de pontuação ou um espaço.

Tentei isso:

```
import re

with open('est.txt', 'r') as f: 
for ligne in f: 
    ligne=re.split('; |, |\s|\.|\n') 
    print (ligne)
```

Só que tenho o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Janaina/Desktop/exo/stats_python/estpy.py", line 5, in <module> ligne=re.split('; |, |\s|\n')
> TypeError: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
> ```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Sei que é algo super básico, mas já tô bloqueada há algum tempo procurando a resposta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) deve receber no mínimo dois argumentos, a expressão regular e a *string* onde você irá aplicá-la. Você está informando somente a expressão regular.

Talvez seja isso que você quer fazer:

```
import re

with open('est.txt', 'r') as f: 
    for ligne in f: 
        ligne = re.split('; |, |\s|\.|\n', ligne) 
        print (ligne)
```

Answer (score 0):

Já agora: pôr sempre o `r` de *raw mode* -- ou seja `r'expressãoregular'` -- por exemplo `'\s'` `r'\s'` são coisas diferentes...

```
import re

with open('est.txt', 'r') as f: 
    for ligne in f:                           # para cada linha
        frases = re.split(r'[;,.!]\s', ligne  # split por pont. espaço
        print(frases)
```